# using values from key-vault in web.config without code

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kudu, azure-keyvault

we have a web app in azure which is deployed directly from our bit-bucket account after commit to a proper branch.  I would like to store our connection strings in key-vault and "just" reference this values in web.config. This is possible if I am using ARM template, I am able to reference the secret from within a parameters file (not the template).
like this

```
 "sqlsvrAdminLoginPassword": {
        "reference": {
          "keyVault": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/{group-name}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vault-name}"
          },
          "secretName": "adminPassword"
        }
      },
      "sqlsvrAdminLogin": {
        "value": "exampleadmin"
      }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter

As our both (test and productive) systems were created manually, we are not using ARM templates at all. Would it be possible to configure build/deployment process in such way that we just provide parameters file + required elements of template file,  and that this values get inserted into web.config during/after build process, If so could you provide some pointer to sample,  or do we have to write code if we want to retrieve values from key-vault with this configuration

thanks
almir

Comment: I would maybe write some sort of deployment script to scrape your web.config file for any references to keyvault, use keyvault's rest API to grab secrets' plain text and then replace back in web.config.

Comment: any idea / pointers  how such a script could look like?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cclayton/2017/01/02/using-key-vault-secrets-in-powershell/ may be useful, as for parsing the web.config, as far as I'm aware it'd be valid XML or JSON so you could quite easily find a library to do that! Or easier, just load the whole file and look for tokens that are like `__KEYVAULT_{keyvaultname}_{secretname}__` or something!

The trouble here is you need some way of securing the client secret which has access to the KV...